# table of distances between 2d points

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to make a function which computes a table of distances between 2d points. This is what I have done, but the table is twice as large as it needs to be.

```
   distance[p_] := 
     Table[p[[i]] - p[[j]], {i, 1, Length[p]}, {j, 1, Length[p]}]
    distance[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}] // TableForm
```

Comment: Look up `DistanceMatrix[]`.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. Thanks ! This solved it ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to create a matrix of the distances between every pair of points would be

```
distancematrix[pts_?MatrixQ, d_Function: EuclideanDistance] := Outer[d, #, #, 1] &@pts // ArrayFlatten
```

Using the (default) Euclidean distance

```
distancematrix[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & \sqrt{2} & 2 \sqrt{2} \\
 \sqrt{2} & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\
 2 \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

and what seems to be used by `DistanceMatrix` (as suggested by @J. M. is somewhat okay)

```
distancematrix[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}, Total[(#1 - #2)^2] &] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 2 & 8 \\
 2 & 0 & 2 \\
 8 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: But the questioner complained that the matrix was twice as large as it needs to be, and you're computing the symmetric distance... keeping that problem.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I interpreted that as the matrix had twice as many elements as it should, since the given code produces a matrix of vectors.  If that was not the intention, and what I gave does not indeed answer the question, I will delete my answer.